# How to use a TexteditingController with a Statenotifierprovider

Tags: flutter, provider

I want to use a texteditting controller with a double data type i.e price name because in my statenotifier provider I had specified that the price should be a double how should i go about it.. below is the foodscreen and the provider code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:kitchen/Provider/fav_food.dart';

class FoodScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const FoodScreen({Key ? key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<FoodScreen> createState() => _FoodScreen();
}

class _FoodScreen extends ConsumerState<FoodScreen>
{
final _keyState=GlobalKey<FormState> ();
final _nameController=TextEditingController();
final _priceController=TextEditingController();
double? priceName=0.0;
void _save()
{
 final enteredName= _nameController.text;
 final  parsedPrice= double.tryParse(_priceController.text);

 if (parsedPrice != null) {
   priceName = parsedPrice;
 } else {
   // Handle the case where parsing fails, e.g., show an error message to the user.
 }


 ref.read(userPlaceProvider.notifier).addFood(enteredName,priceName);
}

  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          title: Text('Food Screen'), // Set the title for the screen
        ),
    body:Form(
      key: _keyState,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            maxLength: 40,
            decoration: const InputDecoration
              (
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Food name',
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children:[
              Expanded(child:
          TextFormField(
            maxLength: 40,
            decoration: const InputDecoration
              (
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Food name',
            ),
          ),),
         const SizedBox(width: 8),
                Expanded(
         child: TextFormField(
            maxLength: 40,
            decoration: const InputDecoration
              (
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Food name',
            ),
          ),),
        ],
      ),

const SizedBox(height: 20,),
              Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: (){},
                  style:ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.green,
                    onPrimary: Colors.white,

                  ),
              child: const Text('Cancel')),
                      const SizedBox(width: 16,),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Define the onPressed logic for the second button
                        },
                        style:ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.green,
                          onPrimary: Colors.white,

                        ),
                        child: const Text('Save'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )


    ],),),);
  }
```

provider code

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kitchen/model/food.dart';

class favFood extends StateNotifier<List<Food>>
{
  favFood():super( const []);

  void addFood(String name,double price)
  {
    final newFood=Food(name:name,price:price);
    state=[newFood,...state];
  }



}

final userPlaceProvider=StateNotifierProvider<favFood,List<Food>> ((ref) =>favFood());
```

I tried creating a variable for the price so that the addFood function would accept the price ,Also tried to declare priceName as a nullable double (double?) to match the return type of double.tryParse but it still refused to work.

Comment: I have only seen you define `_priceController`, not seen you use it yet. Same with `_keyState`

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using double? if then your addFood function requires a double not nullable, try changing like that.

Define first it:

```
double priceName=0.0;
```

Then in your `save` function:

```
void _save()
{
 final enteredName= _nameController.text;
 final  parsedPrice= double.tryParse(_priceController.text);

 if (parsedPrice != null) {
   priceName = parsedPrice!;
 } else {
   // Handle the case where parsing fails, e.g., show an error message to the user.
 }


 ref.read(userPlaceProvider.notifier).addFood(enteredName,priceName);
}
```

In this case if the parsedPrice is null it will remain 0.0, in case you want to avoid it just use the else function to trigger an `Exception` or similar.